# Detect @ in UITextField or UITextView and compare for auto complete

Tags: ios, autocomplete, uitextfield

I am trying to produce something that works the same way Twitter works when composing a Tweet.

My app uses the same syntax of @username for the purpose of messaging. In my compose view I have a UITextView/UITextField the user types a message in,and I would like to detect when a user types the @ and then compare the string following the @ to an array of user names I have for the sake of autocomplete.

I have been following this tutorial which is EXCELLENT: 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/336/auto-complete-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-auto-complete-with-custom-values

These two methods are where I should be performing the detection:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField 
    shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range 
    replacementString:(NSString *)string {
  autocompleteTableView.hidden = NO;

  NSString *substring = [NSString stringWithString:textField.text];
  substring = [substring 
    stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
  [self searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:substring];
  return YES;
}


- (void)searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring:(NSString *)substring {

  // Put anything that starts with this substring into the autocompleteUrls array
  // The items in this array is what will show up in the table view
  [autocompleteUrls removeAllObjects];
  for(NSString *curString in pastUrls) {
    NSRange substringRange = [curString rangeOfString:substring];
    if (substringRange.location == 0) {
      [autocompleteUrls addObject:curString];  
    }
  }
  [autocompleteTableView reloadData];
}
```

I assume it is here that the detection of the @ should occur, but I am not sure how to do so and then compare only the characters immediately following the symbol (and to stop the comparison when it hits white space).

The standard iOS twitter application is a prime example of what I'm looking for. Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: `[str substringFromIndex:[str rangeOfString:@"@"].location + 1]` does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use `NSScanner`. In your `searchAutocompleteEntriesWithSubstring` method, create a scanner with `substring` and run in a loop, initially searching for `@` and then once you have found it searching for a space. Then you can use the scanned string for auto-completion.

Depending on what you do to the string when you find a match dictates how your search algorithm works. You may want to find the range of the last `@` in the `substring` and set the scanner location to there (to avoid processing any pervious usernames) - but, you don't have information about what just changed so it a user went back and inserted a username...